# ASP.NET WebAPI Ajax with progress

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api, progress

I have a really long webAPI request that basically does the follow :

```
1. retrieves a list of item categories from the db 
2. for each category, retrieve all the items in the category
```

Now, the entire process takes a very long time and I don't want the user to wait till the entire process is over, if a category has finished loading I want it to return to the client

Does anyone know how I can do that? Send a request and get progress notifications by the server whenever a part of the request has finished?

Comment: you need to break your request. use for each loop. if elements from first category are downloaded then do something with them before going for second category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) to send the data from the server to the client when it's available.

The other option is polling from the client. The client makes the initial request, which triggers a server side process that prepares the data and keeps it somewhere (in memory, in a database). Then the client polls the server for new available data until the server process finishes.

Answer (score 0):

you need to break your request. use for loop. if elements from first category are downloaded then do something with them before going for second category.

so your request will go inside some loop. You can use Jquery or page methods if you are using asp.net webforms

Answer (score 0):

PushStreamContent might help you:
http://weblogs.asp.net/andresv/asynchronous-streaming-in-asp-net-webapi

Comment: And how do you consume it from the client and keep the user informed of the progress, or show the data as it becomes available?